# Set SoundiD xcode error - trying to play music

Tags: objective-c, xcode, audio

I had this working earlier but for some reason after I've added some more code and then took some of it out, stuff seems to stop working.

The `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);` is causing some error.

```
<+0117>  mov    %eax,-0x18(%ebp)
+0313>  test   %eax,%eax
<+0348>  test   %eax,%eax
```

soundID UInt32  3221214520
soundFileURLRef CFURLRef    0x75217a0
mainBundle  CFBundleRef 0x73122b0
_cmd    SEL 0x511b
self    FirstViewController *   0x7349e90
This are some of the errors I see in the stack trace.

This may seem like stupid questions but I come from Java.

What has caused this error?

Everything was playing fine before. I didn't change any of the code, why does stuff start breaking down.

How do you prevent it from happening and how do I fix?

```
- (IBAction) boom;  {


CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"jarrvvv1", CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL);
UInt32 soundID;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

}

This suggested method for some reason doesn't work.

```
- (IBAction) boom;  {


    UInt32 soundID;


NSURL * soundFileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"jarrvvv1"  withExtension:@"mp3"];
 AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)soundFileURL, &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I just checked, `AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID` does not support mp3!

From the [Multimedia Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2):

> The AudioServicesPlaySystemSound function lets you very simply play short sound files. The simplicity carries with it a few restrictions. Your sound files must be:
>
> No longer than 30 seconds in duration
>   In linear PCM or IMA4 (IMA/ADPCM) format
>   Packaged in a .caf, .aif, or .wav file

**previous answer**

Check that `soundFileURLRef` is returning non-NULL. If it's NULL the mp3 file may not have been copied to your app bundle.

p.s. you can save a little thought by doing resource loading stuff using Foundation (the objective-c API) instead of CoreFoundation:

```
NSURL * soundFileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"jarrvvv1" withExtension:@"mp3"];
NSLog(@"soundFileURL: %@\n", soundFileURL);
UInt32 soundID;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)soundFileURL, &soundID);
```

That way ARC will take care of the memory management for you.

Comment: i took out everything inside the { } and i still gives me the same error.. check out my edited question.. @rythmicfistman

Comment: lol, you're  cool. let me check,.. [2225:207] soundFileURL: file://localhost/Users/Tahj182/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.0/Applications/090E7639-A571-478C-AEC0-F284E9FB956D/clxxxii.app/jarrvvv1.mp3

Comment: @rythmicfistman i'm converting the sound files to .wav right now.. but why did it stop working the first time. the one i had shown in the question was playing around 3:30 o'clock today but now around 8:20 its not working.. thats crazy, java doesn't do that

Comment: you did it bro!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  @rythmicfistman !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! how can i follow you like on twitter or facebook. i dont want to bother you, but I want know important people like you. people like you are amazing, you don't even know it!

Comment: You're welcome! Twitter handle is in my bio and don't forget to mark the question as answered!

Comment: @rhythmfistman i don't have enough reputation points...  i'm about to tweet you..